# Wordpress on google cloud. I cant install a plugin or upload an image

Tags: wordpress, gcloud

I installed Wordpress to google cloud but when i want to install a plugin, it is asking for ftp credentials.

I added "define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');" to wp-config.php file.

I have to give right permission to folders.

What is the giving permission code line for gcloud ssh?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/ please check this one

Comment: thank you very much i am checking this plugin. Uploading images & using plugins for building a wordpress website on any hosting company should be easy. I don't know why google cloud is so complex. i am deeply lost myself at gcloud ssh.

Comment: could you please tell me output of the plugin.In case you are test it.

Comment: Did you use Google Cloud Launcher (Click to Deploy / Bitnami) to deploy WordPress stack? and what plug-in are you trying to install?

Answer (score 4):

i solve the "insue" doing this

```
nano /var/www/html/wp-config.php
```

add the following line

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

then

```
sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/html
sudo chmod  755  /var/www/html
```

works for my on click to deploy intallation